# How i can hide my api from being public as i am using it in jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, api-design

i don't want public to know my application api paths.but i am using those under jquery ajax url to interact with the back end.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  type:'get'
}).done(function() {
  //some function
});
```

Comment: You can't. Just ensure that it can only be used with authorization.

Comment: Every request that is made from a page can easily be inspected in browser dev tools network or other networking apps user has installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way to prevent users from inspecting your application's network requests, and no point in doing so anyway. Once you exposed your API on the internet it became public, whether you were referencing it in your Web Application or not. It's just a little more visible now. Either way, you'll have to add an authentication layer to your server to ensure that you're only handling traffic from appropriate clients.